# Flutter --released mode app getting design error but working perfectly in debug mode

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

After my app development with the Flutter debug mode app is running smoothly in the emulator as well as real device smoothly but in release mode, it's getting a design error, in debug mode, there is no error or design overflow but a grey color showing

```
I/flutter (21212): Another exception was thrown: Instance of'DiagnosticsProperty<void>'
```

[image]

Comment: Try `flutter build apk --no-shrink`

Answer (score 0):

Flutter in debug mode will throw exception on to console and renders the UI. But once you build the app in release any UI layout issues will shown as grey.
You have to fix the error that is showing in console in debug mode in order to get the UI in release mode.